# WebStorm: Live Edit registers no changes, even when changing significant parts of html, css,

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Ok, so Live Edit isn't working for me because it isn't registering any changes made to the html document and therefore doesn't change the page displayed in Chrome.

Whenever I hit the update Application button manually it says:

> Live Edit: Loaded resources are up to date. Nothing to update

It is doing the "Highlight current element in browser on caret change", so it is successfully connected to Chrome, but it isn't noticing any changes in the document.

Anybody got a clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: works for me. I'd suggest creating a support ticket, attaching a screencast that shows your steps, etc.